# How to get a student_id from attendance table with maximum attendance?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table 'tbl_student_daily_attendance' as following

```
daily_id|stud_id|status
1       |1      |0
2       |1      |1
3       |1      |0
4       |1      |1
5       |2      |1
6       |2      |1
7       |2      |0
8       |2      |1
```

The status column stands for present and absent that is 1 and 0 respectively.

The output that i want is the stud_id with maximum presence (that is status=1)

In the above case it should return stud_id = 2

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the total amount by `stud_id` which `status = 1`. Then order by total amount and get the first one (the maximum presence (that is status=1))

**Query #1**

```
SELECT stud_id
FROM tbl_student_daily_attendance t1
GROUP BY stud_id
ORDER BY SUM(status = 1)  DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Result**

```
| stud_id |
| ------- |
| 2       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dLMJQwG44HooExXUnLfTyn/0)

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub-query like below

```
 select stud_id
   from 
 tbl_student_daily_attendance
 group by stud_id
 having sum(status) =
  (  select max(s) from
    (select sum(status) s,
   stud_id
   from tbl_student_daily_attendance
   group by stud_id
   ) t1
  )
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dLMJQwG44HooExXUnLfTyn/1

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `GROUP BY` with `SUM()` :

```
SELECT stud_id
FROM tbl_student_daily_attendance t1 s
GROUP BY stud_id
ORDER BY SUM(status) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This will give only one row, if you have a ties with present with different students then you can do :

```
SELECT stud_id
FROM tbl_student_daily_attendance t1 s
GROUP BY stud_id
HAVING SUM(status) = (SELECT MAX(status)
                      FROM (SELECT stud_id, SUM(status) as status
                            FROM tbl_student_daily_attendance t1 s
                            GROUP BY stud_id
                           )
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make use of subqueries to handle the scenario.
First you can fetch the stud_id and their corresponding count by grouping them on student id with a where clause on status.

```
Select stud_id,count(*) as count from tbl_student_daily_attendance where status=1 
group by stud_id
```

Then on the result of the above query you can fetch the max of the count with the student id. The complete query would look as below:

```
select stud_id,max(count) from (Select stud_id,count(*) as count from 
tbl_student_daily_attendance where status=1 group by stud_id);
```

I hope this helps!!!